# Distributing Read Traffic Amongst RDS Read-Replicas

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I've launched a rds db instance and 2 read-replicas. AWS FAQ says that it is up to my application to determine how read traffic will be distributed amongst them. I want to know what is the best way to do this?

Comment: "Best" depends on your application constraints. If you have multiple application deployments, each of them can access one of your read replicas; alternatively, for a single deployment, one kind of transaction of your application can access one of the replicas, while other kind of transaction can access another replica. They guarantee the data will be on every read replica, but they won't balance the DB read transactions for you. That is up to you determine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=253641

Comment: link is dead, link-only answers are not good for this reason